# MySQL kill sleep connections

Tags: mysql, shell

My DB seems to have almost 100 "sleep" connections and I believe it would be better to get rid of them. I have found the following script which helps me analyze all tables in a DB from the command line. Does anybody know of a similar one liner which can kill all "sleep" connections?

```
mysql -p -D<database> -B -e "SHOW TABLES" \
| awk '{print "CHECK TABLE "$1";"}' \
| mysql -p -D<database>
```

Comment: In my experience, those idle connections normally come from PHP-powered web applications that use persistent connections. If they are an issue, PHP allows to disables them.

Comment: Alvaro, I am not using persistent connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the wait_timeout variable to a shorter time than the default and it should kill off the connections once they exceed this time value.

From what I've read there is some bugginess and connections will still randomly hang around, especially under load, but the wait_timeout variable would be the place to start.

Comment: Brian, for a number of reasons I need to keep the wait_timeout value high. I am thus looking for a short one line script like the one I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

You may use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` instead of `SHOW TABLES`. I'm not much familiar with `awk` linux utility but I think you can do all sorts of pattern matching there in.

Alternatively, you can write a script to query MySQL for "SHOW PROCESSLIST", parse the resultset for sleeping connections and accordingly use `KILL <process id>`

Comment: Abhay, this is exactly the path I was looking to go down, but it seems we have the same, ehm "limitations" :)

Comment: hehe, right! But perhaps a little playing around with "awk" is all you need. As I understand it is a powerful utility and you can run all shell statements in it (not very sure though). But since my limitations, I think it is much safer to do it via scripts. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `mysql -e "show processlist" | awk '/Sleep/ {print $1}'` ; do mysql -e "KILL $i;"; done
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-kill-all-mysql-sleeping-queries