# Wordpress site -- Error connecting to database - only on high traffic

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-connection

I have a wordpress 3.5.1 site that's getting a little bit of traffic (80 concurrent visitors, ~5 clicks/pageviews per second). The site runs fine until it spikes to ~85 visitors. There are usually 4 admins logged in at the same time. The site has 8 custom post types--Posts has 3500 posts, and Press Releases (a custom post type) has 13000 posts. All of this is paginated on the site, so there are never more than 20 posts showing on any one page.

The only plugins I'm using are wp-pagenavi and w3totalcache.

I set WP_DEBUG_LOG to true and logged the errors. The main error I'm getting (besides various notices and warnings unrelated to this issue) is mysql has reached the max_user_connections limit.

My current max_user_connections is set to 75. I tried to set it higher, but the cpu can't handle the load (4 Quad Core CPUs at 2.17GHz each and 4GB of RAM).

What could be causing so many connections?

I've viewed the mysql processes running when the errors happened and there are many connections that say "SLEEPING" or "SLEEP" (probably 15-20). I also noticed via the process logs that httpd is restarting quite often during the peak traffic times.

Any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

NOTE: Please do not respond if your answer is to check my wp-config.php file and make sure my username, password, and host are correct. This is NOT the issue. The site works fine under normal traffic.

Comment: Check the 1st answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083060/mysql-kill-sleep-connections.

Comment: This sounds like an option (i.e. reducing the wait_timout variable), but what would be the impact of this? Will this start killing connections that are actually being used? I want to make sure that admins don't get kicked out when they're trying to edit something. Also, what would be a reasonable number to set this variable to?

Comment: This won't affect logged in user sessions. Your question can better be answered in serverfault as it's more server settings related. Check this answer regarding the same subject to get a better idea: http://serverfault.com/a/71379.

Answer (score 0):

The database server is dropping out due to high loads. What's in the error logs? What's the size of the database? Have you used mysqltuner.pl to check the query load and caching settings for the MySQL server in my.cnf? https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl

WordPress can really bog down the database with many post/page revisions. Delete them with a plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revision-control/  I've dropped databases to 10% of their original size with a resulting huge increase in performance.

Comment: I installed revision-control and limited it to 2 revisions. That's reduced the size of the db a bit. The total size is ~400MB. I've never heard of mysqltuner. I'll look into that for sure. I don't feel like there really should be a high load on the server with only 80 visitors and a few admins logged in.

Comment: There will be a load with that many posts and CPT items. mysqltuner is easy to use and will give you recommendations on adjusting my.cnf to be able to better cache queries.